# Passing pure XML in react render

Tags: xml, node.js, reactjs

I get some data from server and i need to fit this data in the table inside react element.

Now i'm parsing JSON array i got from the server with [tableify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-tableify) and getting a pure string with xml table. Then i'm parsing string like:

```
    componentDidMount: function(){
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.innerHTML = tableify(this.props.data);
        var div = wrapper.firstChild;
        this.setState({
            data: div   
        });
    }
```

and getting pure XML object inside this.props.data.

How to parse this xml data into render of the react element? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using [reactable](https://github.com/glittershark/reactable) and don't even need tableify anymore.